# Angular 8 - Animate image src change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I am trying to create an animation in angular 8 that pulls in and out when the source is changed. Currently this only works when the image first loads, but does not continue to animate when the src is changed.

Here is what i have so far:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

....
....

@Component({
    selector: "app-page",
    templateUrl: "app.page.html",
    styleUrls: ["app.page.scss"],
    animations: [
        trigger('EnterLeave', [
            state('flyIn', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
            transition('* => *', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
                animate('0.5s 300ms ease-in')
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                animate('0.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
```

**app.page.html**

This code here is what the animation is bound to. I added a function to make it easier to test. This just changes the image property value in the component to a random image source

```
<img *ngIf="image" [src]="image" [@EnterLeave]="'flyIn'" (click)="changeImage()" />
```

**changeImage()**

```
    changeImage() {
        const sources = [
                       'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597741176776-25457188eafd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max',
                       'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597905040495-0aa996018b92?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max',
                       'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596280364433-7742f3fb771e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max'];

        let randSrc = sources[Math.floor(Math.random() * sources.length)];
        this.image = randSrc;
    }
```

So this code is working fine in terms of the animation on the initial load, but i can't seem to figure out how to animate the image so that it pulls in and out when the property value is changed programatically as it just seems to change suddenly without the specified animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property `backgroundImage` instead of `src` then you just need to update your style in the component using ngStyle and change the url of your background image.

That should look like that : 
Your HTML component :

```html
<img class="animate-img" [ngStyle]="getImageStyle()" (click)="changeImage()"/>
```

Your CSS file :

```css
.animate-img{
  width: 512px; // Whatever size you want for your image
  height: 512px; 
  transition: background-image 500ms; // Important for transition
}
```

Your new method `getImageStyle()` in the component.ts

```js
getImageStyle(){
  return {
      //this.image is the image URL that has been generated by your changeImage() function
      backgroundImage:`url(${this.image})`,
      //It's important to redefine the background position because it will not be used if no `backgroundImage` is provided 
      backgroundPosition:'center center',
      backgroundRepeat:'no-repeat',
      backgroundSize:'cover'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the animations using :enter and :leave not work in this way. This "aliases" work when you has a *ngIf.

So I suggest you use two images. A good way to mannage two images is enclosed in a div wrapper. So imagine some like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img *ngIf="toogle"
       [@enterLeave]
       [src]="imageToogle"
       (click)="changeImage()"
  />
  <img *ngIf="!toogle"
       [@enterLeave]
       [src]="imageNotToogle"
       (click)="changeImage()"
  />
</div>
```

We can use a .css like

```
.wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;

}
.wrapper img{
  float:left;
  margin-right:-100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
.wrapper::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}
```

See that in this way (using float:left and margin-rigth) the two images are placed in the same position, the wrapper::after, makes that clear the float:left without add any additional div

Our animation becomes like

```
  animations: [
    trigger('enterLeave', [
      transition(':enter', [                    //when "enter"
        style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), //first translate the image
                                                   //after, animate to (*)
        animate('0.5s 300ms ease-in',style({ transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [  //when leave animate to
        animate('0.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

(*)Really you can omit the style in this case because really is not style

```
    animate('0.5s 300ms ease-in')
```

Now declare three variables: toogle, imageToogle and imageNotToogle and our function changeImagen

```
  public toogle: boolean = true;
  sources = [
    'https://picsum.photos/400/300?random=1',
    'https://picsum.photos/400/300?random=2',
    'https://picsum.photos/400/300?random=3',
    'https://picsum.photos/400/300?random=4',
  ];

  imageToogle = this.sources[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sources.length)];
  imageNotToogle = null;
  changeImage() {
    let randSrc = this.sources[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sources.length)];
    this.toogle = !this.toogle;
    if (this.toogle) this.imageToogle = randSrc;
    else this.imageNotToogle = randSrc;
  }
}
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwygmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

We can do it also using an unique image using (@animation.done). In this case we have some like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img [@fly]="state"
       (@fly.done)="state==-1 && changeImageFly()"
       [src]="image"
       (click)="changeImageFly()"
  />
</div>
```

And using

```
animations: [
    trigger('fly', [
      transition('*=>1', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
        animate('0.5s 300ms ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      ]),
      transition('1=>-1', [
        animate('0.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
      ]),
    ]),
]

  image = this.sources[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sources.length)];
  state:number=1;
  changeImageFly() {
    this.image = this.sources[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sources.length)];
    this.state=-this.state
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to animate the image when **querying the src**
since the src attribute is the only attribute that changes.

```js
export const fadeIn = trigger( "fadeInAnimation", [
  transition( '* => *', [

    query(        <---------THIS
      "img[src]", <---------THIS
      [
        style( { opacity: 0 } ),
        animate( ".8s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)", style( { opacity: 1 } ) )
      ],
      {
        optional: true
      }
    )
  ] )
] );
```